# How can I display apps installed that can download a file upon user click

Tags: android, android-intent, download, intentfilter

How to display a list of apps which could download a file in Android?

for example: if a user clicks the download button, if the user has two apps on his phone that can download, they will show those two apps that can download the file, so my question is, what intent action here should be?  (like `Intent.ACTION.SEND`)

Answer (score -1):

There is no any specific intent for downloading so you can use **ACTION_VIEW** and let browser decide to download

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it is NOT what i am looking for ,what I want is upon clicking a button the user will be requested to specify the file download
method using one of apps installed on the phone

Comment: @Toaster I don't think so. You don't click a download button to display list of apps but to download a file. Android by default lists the apps and lets you select them that can handle the intent you provided. If he wanted to implement apps listing inside his own app, he shouldn't have mentioned about action intent.
So down voting this answer doesn't makes sense at all. Anyway, thank you for your reply.